# Block Diagonal of list of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to use `block_diag` to make a block diagonal matrix
of multiple matrices.

Let's say I have matrices `A`, `B`, and `C`. I can simply write:

```
block_diag(A, B, C)
```

However, I do wish to have more matrices later on.

How do I combine `A`, `B`, and `C` into a list of matrices `X` so that 
I can write:

```
block_diag(X)
```

I tried using `[A, B, C]` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the star operator (`*`), which spreads out the contents of an iterable as positional function arguments. (I have chosen to use an immutable [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples), but the list `[A, B, C]` would work equally well.)

```
X = (A, B, C)

print(block_diag(*X))
```